# CSS: borders between table columns only

Tags: css

Is there a way, using CSS, to show borders in a table between columns only (not on the outer edges)?

Answer (score 126, accepted):

**Edit 2**

Erasmus has a better one-liner [below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3313456/css-borders-between-table-columns-only/22775925#22775925)

---

Not without tricky css selectors and extra markup and the like.

Something like this might do (using CSS selectors):

```
table {
    border:none;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

table td {
    border-left: 1px solid #000;
    border-right: 1px solid #000;
}

table td:first-child {
    border-left: none;
}

table td:last-child {
    border-right: none;
}
```

**Edit**

To clarify @jeroen's comment blow, all you'd really need is:

```
table { border: none; border-collapse: collapse; }
table td { border-left: 1px solid #000; }
table td:first-child { border-left: none; }
```

Comment: Note: IE6-8 does not support `:last-child` (and spotty on `:first-child` according to http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html

Comment: Just use a left border, then there's no need for the `:last-child`.

Comment: @jereon: True, didn't really think it through all the way. But the basic point is the same.

Comment: my comment was mainly directed at Scott to counter the problem he brought up; I completely agree with the idea of your answer, you can even get rid of the first line as far as I´m concerned :-) +1

Comment: Use selectivizr for ie8 :last-child

Comment: It seem's that this does not play nice when using rowspan.

Answer (score 146):

I know this is an old question, but there is a simple, ***one line solution*** which works consistently for Chrome, Firefox, etc., as well as IE8 and above (and, for the most part, works on IE7 too - see http://www.quirksmode.org/css/selectors/ for details):

```
table td + td { border-left:2px solid red; }
```

The output is something like this:

```
Col1 | Col2 | Col3
```

What is making this work is that you are defining a border only on table cells which are adjacent to another table cell.  In other words, you're applying the CSS to all cells in a row except the first one.

By applying a left border to the second through the last child, it gives the appearance of the line being "between" the cells.

Comment: This definitely deserves note as it is still valid and very simple

Comment: how would you do this in-line with the HTML?

Comment: Yeah, this is definitely the better solution 

Comment: Lovely solution, smart usage of simple css rules

Comment: thanks, its very simple and worked!

Comment: `td + td { border-left:2px solid red; }` is enough, you don't need `table`, because `td` is always inside `table`.

Answer (score 3):

Borders on tables are always a bit flaky. One possibility would be to add a border-right declaration to each table cell except for the ones in right-most column. If you're using any kind of table-spacing this won't work very well.

Another option would be to use a 1px high background image with the borders inside it, but that'll only work if you can guarantee the width of each cell at all times.

Another possibility is to experiment with colgroup / col. This had fairly horrible support cross-browser the last time i looked at it but could have improved since then: http://www.webmasterworld.com/forum83/6826.htm

Comment: This is rather terrible advice - CSS offers an easy way for relatively recent (IE8+) to accomplish this elegantly.

Comment: Bear in mind this answer (and the question) are both from 2010, half a decade ago, back when IE6 was still under active support for many developers. Additionally the CSS methods for achieving table borders at the time were impossible for pretty much every HTML email renderer available. Thanks for the necromancy, though!

Comment: Haha, didn't realise that, as the accepted answer was edited only a few weeks ago :).

Answer (score 3):

Inside `<td>`, use `style="border-left:1px solid #colour;"`

Comment: I think the spirit of the question is 'using CSS to style the table' rather than putting CSS in specific places.

Answer (score 2):

I may be simplifying the issue, but does
td {border-right: 1px solid red;}
work for your table setup?

Comment: No, because then there will be a border on the right of the table. I don't want a border on the right or left edge of the table, only between columns.

Comment: If you apply a class to your final column then you can remove the border-right declaration from the final one. It does require manual adjustment, but if it's a static page then it's actually the best solution.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set a `border-right` on the td's then target the last tds in a row to set the border to `none`. Ways to target:

1. Set a class on the last `td` of each row and use that
2. If it is a set number of cells and only targeting newer browers then 3 cells wide can use `td + td + td`
3. Or better (with new browsers) `td:last-child`

Answer (score 2):

I used this in a style sheet for three columns separated by vertical borders and it worked fine:

```css
#column-left {
     border-left: 1px solid #dddddd;
}
#column-center {
     /*no border needed/*
}
#column-right {
     border-right: 1px solid #dddddd;
}
```

The column on the left gets a border on the right, the column on the right gets a border on the left and the the middle column is already taken care of by the left and right.

If your columns are inside a div/wrapper/table/etc... don't forget to add extra space to accomodate the width of the borders.

Answer (score 2):

Take a table with class name `column-bordered-table` then add this below css.This will work with `bootstrap` table too

```
.column-bordered-table thead td {
    border-left: 1px solid #c3c3c3;
    border-right: 1px solid #c3c3c3;
}

.column-bordered-table td {
    border-left: 1px solid #c3c3c3;
    border-right: 1px solid #c3c3c3;
}

.column-bordered-table tfoot tr {
    border-top: 1px solid #c3c3c3;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #c3c3c3;
}
```

see the output below
**N:B You have to add table header backgorund color as per you requirement**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

See table's `rules` attribute - https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html#h-11.3.1

Answer (score 0):

There's no easy way of doing this, other than doing something like class="lastCell" on the last td in each tr, and then setting your css up like this:

```
#table td {
    border-right: 5px solid red
}

.lastCell {
    border-right: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Today we have some cool selectors, namely [:not()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) and [child selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child).

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

th:not(:last-child),
td:not(:last-child) {
  border-right: 2px solid coral;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>header 1</th>
      <th>header 2</th>
      <th>header 3</th>
      <th>header 4</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1, 1</td>
      <td>1, 2</td>
      <td>1, 3</td>
      <td>1, 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2, 1</td>
      <td>2, 2</td>
      <td>2, 3</td>
      <td>2, 4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Personally, I was more interested in this:

```css
    table {
      border-collapse: collapse;
    }

    th:nth-child(2),
    td:nth-child(2) {
      border: 2px solid coral;
      border-top: none;
      border-bottom: none;
    }
```

```html
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>header 1</th>
          <th>header 2</th>
          <th>header 3</th>
          <th>header 4</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>1, 1</td>
          <td>1, 2</td>
          <td>1, 3</td>
          <td>1, 4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>2, 1</td>
          <td>2, 2</td>
          <td>2, 3</td>
          <td>2, 4</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```