# Table outline border and column border only in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, html-table

I want a table like below, only the `outline_border` (?) and `column border` to be in the table, but when I try there is a dark fade border in my rows:

[image]

```
How I achieve so far:
```

[image]

> How can I get a table with outline border and column border, but not in a row. I used bootstrap CSS.

If i used table class `table-borderless` the rows line and all lines were gone except the `outline-border`, but I want column border to be in the table

[I try like this questions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3313493/8826120)

Please play it below here:

```css
table {
    border:1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
table tr {
  border-left: 1px solid #000;
  border-right: 1px solid #000;
}

table td {
    border-left: 1px solid #000;
    border-right: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>

<table class="table table-small">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Col1</th>
      <th>Col2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>name</td>
      <td>123</td>
      <td>456</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>name2</td>
      <td>xyz</td>
      <td>abc</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>name</td>
      <td>123</td>
      <td>456</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>name2</td>
      <td>xyz</td>
      <td>abc</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>name</td>
      <td>123</td>
      <td>456</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>name2</td>
      <td>xyz</td>
      <td>abc</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>name</td>
      <td>123</td>
      <td>456</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>name2</td>
      <td>xyz</td>
      <td>abc</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that bootstrap overwrites part of your definitions. To avoid this, you can make certain CSS `!important`.

**EDIT**: Horizontal lines between table cells removed.

```css
.table {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.table thead th {
  border-top: 1px solid #000!important;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000!important;
  border-left: 1px solid #000;
  border-right: 1px solid #000;
}

.table td {
  border-left: 1px solid #000;
  border-right: 1px solid #000;
  border-top: none!important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<table class="table table-small">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Col1</th>
      <th>Col2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>name</td>
      <td>123</td>
      <td>456</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>name2</td>
      <td>xyz</td>
      <td>abc</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>name</td>
      <td>123</td>
      <td>456</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>name2</td>
      <td>xyz</td>
      <td>abc</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>name</td>
      <td>123</td>
      <td>456</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>name2</td>
      <td>xyz</td>
      <td>abc</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>name</td>
      <td>123</td>
      <td>456</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>name2</td>
      <td>xyz</td>
      <td>abc</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks, how can I make the line hidden between data: Example:- between rows 1 and 2, there is a gray color line... How can I remove that line?

Comment: @Vpa I made an edit in the code to remove the horizontal lines between cells.

Comment: thank you so much, it works perfectly...

I remove (border-top: 1px solid #000!important;) and still same table I got, maybe not required... anyway thanks

Comment: suppose I want to make a border-line between the rows, Example: On 3rd rows 3rd and 4th column I want to make a border to highlight these are totals, how can I make that and, also on last rows, but the whole column...

Comment: If I put inline CSS to the <td> then border can come, but is there any better way

Answer (score 0):

My question for the above comment is, I can achieve what I want like below, but I have to use inline CSS everywhere. Is there any better approach to work with, not just inline CSS

```css
.table {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.table thead th {
  border-top: 1px solid #000!important;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000!important;
  border-left: 1px solid #000;
  border-right: 1px solid #000;
}

.table td {
  border-left: 1px solid #000;
  border-right: 1px solid #000;
  border-top: none!important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<table class="table table-small">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Col1</th>
      <th>Col2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>name</td>
      <td>123</td>
      <td>456</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>name2</td>
      <td>xyz</td>
      <td>abc</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>sub-total</td>
      <td style="border-bottom: 1px solid #000;border-top: 1px solid #000!important;">123</td>
      <td style="border-bottom: 1px solid #000;border-top: 1px solid #000!important">456</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>name2</td>
      <td>xyz</td>
      <td>abc</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>name</td>
      <td>123</td>
      <td>456</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>name2</td>
      <td>xyz</td>
      <td>abc</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>name</td>
      <td>123</td>
      <td>456</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="border-top: 1px solid #000!important">
      <td>##</td>
      <td>Total</td>
      <td>xyz</td>
      <td>abc</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Only this can done by adding these styles in our head tag

```
.invoice-table {
        border: 1px solid black;
    }

    .invoice-table thead th {
        border: 1px solid #000!important;

    }

    .invoice-table td {
        border: 1px solid #000;

    }
```

Import: to have line for each tr we can simple add to

```
<tr style="border-top: 1px solid #000!important">
```